# SQL JOIN two tables: inner join on one column and left join on another

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
t1: (name, dt, value1)
t2: (name, dt, valuu2)
```

I want to inner join on the column `name` and left join on the column `dt`. In other words:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 on t1.name=t2.name
LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.dt=t2.dt
```

Semantically, I want the following as a correlated SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t1.name=t2.name) AS t2_ on t1.date = t2_.date
```

But that is going to be very slow. What would be a good way to implement this?

---EDIT--

Here is a small example as requested:

```
create or replace table t1(name integer, date integer, value integer);
create or replace table t2(name integer, date integer, value integer);

INSERT into t1 values(1, 10, 100);
INSERT into t1 values(2, 10, 200);
INSERT into t1 values(3, 30, 300);
INSERT into t1 values(4, 40, 400);

INSERT into t2 values(1, 10, 100);
INSERT into t2 values(2, 20, 200);
INSERT into t2 values(3, 30, 300);


SELECT *
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t1.name=t2.name) AS t2_ on t1.date = t2_.date
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: Date is a reserved word, i.e. delimit as `"date"`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words

Comment: It seems some SQL implementation allows it, but I fixed it now.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by an inner join on one column and an outer join on another? Inner and outer join semantics are defined in terms of the (whole) join condition, not in terms of individual columns of any table.  Examples would be good.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I just edited the question.

Comment: Can there be duplicate `name`s in t1?

Comment: No, there can't.

Comment: Can you add a sample of a couple of rows in each table and sample of what you want the results of your query to be?

Comment: Just use a compound condition: `left join on t2.name = t1.name and t2.dt = t2.dt`

Comment: That's... just a left join on both columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to inner join on the column `name` and left join on the column `dt`.

Join type is defined in terms of the whole join condition, so what you are asking for does not make sense unless you mean you want to join a table twice.

From your clarification, I think you mean that you want rows for all `name`s that are present in both tables, for each `name` the columns of `t1` and either (i) the row(s) of `t2` for which the dates match, or (ii) nulls.  You present a version with a correlated inline view, and apparently you are concerned with query performance.

You cannot have both inner and outer semantics with the same join, so you are going to need either a subquery or multiple joins, but it should be possible to do better than the query presented in the question.  One possibility would be to perform the outer join, and filter out the unwanted rows based on a(n uncorrelated) suquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN t2
    on t1.name=t2.name and t1.dt=t2.dt
WHERE t1 in (select name from t2)
```

Another possibility would be to use an *un*correlated inline view to form the inner join, and then left-join to that:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
    FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
  ) t1_
  LEFT JOIN t2
    on t1_.name=t2.name and t1_.dt=t2.dt
```

The `SELECT DISTINCT` could be costly there, but that would be difficult to predict even with more information about the database.

Comment: The second query is better although assuming t2 has a primary key it's inclusion in the sub query could make the join faster than using `name` e.g. `LEFT JOIN t2.id = _t1.t2_id AND t1_.dt=t2.dt`

Comment: Based on what I'm reading I think you only need one join. You don't seem to care about the names that match without a corresponding date.

Answer (score 2):

Use differents aliases when join same table twice :

```
SELECT *
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 on t1.name = t2.name
LEFT JOIN t2 t2_ on t1.date = t2_.date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.*, 
case when t1.dt = t2.dt then t2.value2
else null end as value2
from t1 inner join t2 on  t1.name = t2.name
```

Comment: @engineersmnky Um, yeah.  That's what he said he wanted

Comment: @engineersmnky you're right.  Let me rethink this

Comment: @engineersmnky What about this?